# log file into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, file, logging

I have a log file:

```
20-04-21 15:04:54.355 -07 000000105 INF: Y Motor: Loading Y Motion Profile for 0.830 mm

20-04-21 15:04:54.355 -07 000000105 INF: Y Motor: The Y Motion Profile for 0.830 mm is already loaded, skipping

20-04-21 15:04:54.355 -07 000000105 INF: SipperMotor: Set Sipper Position Down

20-04-21 15:04:54.355 -07 000000105 INF: FPGA: Xmit SIPDOWN\n [SipperMotor]

20-04-21 15:05:07.665 -07 000000136 INF: FPGA: Recv SIPDOWN

20-04-21 15:05:07.665 -07 000000105 INF: FPGA: 'SIPDOWN' command took 0 ms to send, 13300 ms to get response, and 13305 ms overall
```

1. There is no header
2. I would like to make the first column split for the date ##-##-##
3. The second column should be ##:##:##.###
4. The third column should be -##
5. The fourth column should XXX:
6. The fifth column shoul dbe everything else as a text

Answer (score 1):

I would read the file as a single column and extract:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, sep='\t')
df = df[0].str.extract('(\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+) (.*)$')
```

Output:

```
    0         1               2          3  4
--  --------  ------------  ---  ---------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  20-04-21  15:04:54.355  -07  000000105  INF: Y Motor: Loading Y Motion Profile for 0.830 mm
 1  20-04-21  15:04:54.355  -07  000000105  INF: Y Motor: The Y Motion Profile for 0.830 mm is already loaded, skipping
 2  20-04-21  15:04:54.355  -07  000000105  INF: SipperMotor: Set Sipper Position Down
 3  20-04-21  15:04:54.355  -07  000000105  INF: FPGA: Xmit SIPDOWN\n [SipperMotor]
 4  20-04-21  15:05:07.665  -07  000000136  INF: FPGA: Recv SIPDOWN
 5  20-04-21  15:05:07.665  -07  000000105  INF: FPGA: 'SIPDOWN' command took 0 ms to send, 13300 ms to get response, and 13305 ms overall
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have fixed width formatted lines. You can use [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

```py
df = pd.read_fwf('d1.csv', colspecs=[(0,8),(9,21),(22,25),(26,35),(36,-1)], header=None)

df
           0               1       2        3                                                   4
0   20-04-21    15:04:54.355    -7.0    105.0   INF: Y Motor: Loading Y Motion Profile for 0.8...
1   20-04-21    15:04:54.355    -7.0    105.0   INF: Y Motor: The Y Motion Profile for 0.830 m...
2   20-04-21    15:04:54.355    -7.0    105.0   INF: SipperMotor: Set Sipper Position Down
3   20-04-21    15:04:54.355    -7.0    105.0   INF: FPGA: Xmit SIPDOWN\n [SipperMotor]
4   20-04-21    15:05:07.665    -7.0    136.0   INF: FPGA: Recv SIPDOWN
5   20-04-21    15:05:07.665    -7.0    105.0   INF: FPGA: 'SIPDOWN' command took 0 ms to send...
```

> ***`colspecs` : list of tuple (int, int) or ‘infer’. optional***
>
> A list of tuples giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., `[from, to[` ). String value `‘infer’` can be used to instruct the parser to try detecting the column specifications from the first 100 rows of the data which are not being skipped via skiprows (`default=’infer’)`.
>   - [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)